# RSS Viewer web part not working in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rss

I have been trying to insert a RSS Viewer web part in my SP 2010 site however i receive the error:

ProtocolError occured trying to complete the request. The server returned a status code of : ProxyAuthenticationRequired and the status description is : "Proxy Authentication Required"

This seems to only happen when a feed does not end in ".rss". I have tried external and internal Sharepoint sites and MSDN feeds and they all work fine.

Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of longshot but permission might be given to have the .rss mime type to be handled by your webserver. Maybe you can have a look there. If there is a handler for the .rss type. Maybe you can copy that for the extension you do want.

See here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx
and here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240%28WS.10%29.aspx

Are you making sure you are sending the correct mime type with your request/response?
Try using wireshark or fiddler to inspect the network traffic. Sometimes there is some negotiating in network packets which can give vital information.